# A is a $3 \times n$ matrix whose columns span $\mathbb{R}^3$ describe how to find a $n \times 3$ matrix D so that $AD = I_3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> A is a $3 \times n$ matrix whose columns span $\mathbb{R}^3$ describe how to find a $n \times 3$ matrix $D$ so that $AD = I_3$

So I know that I can let $I_3  = \begin{bmatrix}e_1&e_2&e_3\end{bmatrix}$ and similarly $D = \begin{bmatrix}d_1&d_2&d_3\end{bmatrix}$

I also know that $AD = I_3 \equiv Ad_1 = e_1, Ad_2 = e_2, Ad_3 = e_3$

But to prove $AD= I_3$ would I just multiply by $A$ on both sides to get:

$(A)D = (A)\begin{bmatrix}d_1&d_2&d_3\end{bmatrix}$ which $\implies$ $AD = \begin{bmatrix}e_1&e_2&e_3\end{bmatrix}$ which means $AD = I_3$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the columns of A span $\mathbb{R^3}$, you know that $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are linear combinations of the columns of A.

Therefore there are solutions $d_1, d_2, d_3$ to the equations $A x=e_i$ for $1\le i\le 3$;

so if you let $D=\begin{bmatrix} d_1&d_2&d_3\end{bmatrix}$, then $AD=I$ as you have shown.